# Reporting services deployment for external users?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, dashboard

In most organizations, are external users (outside the organization) granted access to SSRS reports by going directly to Report Manager with limited permissions to view their reports only, for example, or do organizations more often create a separate dashboard website which pulls in the reports from SSRS?

I'm asking because currently I see a situation where there is a separate .NET site which pulls reports from SSRS, and I'm curious if this is a possibly unnecessary extra layer (the separate website), or do companies often create a separate dashboard site due to limitations(?) of SSRS Report Manager, or for security reasons? For example, could the Reporting Services Report Manager interface be customized to look like an organization's website reporting interface (with their logo, colors, etc), and not the standard out of the box Report Manager?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do companies often create a separate dashboard site due to limitations(?) of SSRS Report Manager, or for security reasons?

Yes and no; it's going to depend a lot on the needs of the company.  If Report Manager isn't doing what you need, then a custom solution is really the only option...

> For example, could the Reporting Services Report Manager interface be customized to look like an organization's website reporting interface (with their logo, colors, etc), and not the standard out of the box Report Manager?

To a *very* limited degree, yes.  You can modify the CSS sheets being used by SSRS, and inject some Javascript to apply some style hacks, but what you'll be able to accomplish is still quite limited.  See here for getting started:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345247.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the info...a follow up question...is Report Manager meant to be used as a external user facing report interface (over the Internet)? Or is it's intended audience more so internal company users (Intranet)? Or either?

Comment: Out of the box, it's absolutely meant for an internal userbase: the stock authentication options utilize Active Directory.  You *can* sling some custom code to authenticate against whatever credential pool you want, but that starts you down a slippery slope.  If Report Manager doesn't meet your needs, you could always develop a custom interface, and still leverage the ReportServer service for your report processing.